# mongodb query documents by specifying range of dynamic key data

Tags: mongodb

I've a typical data stored in bit weird way (may not make much sense but its historical data stored as such):

```
{
   1:{"text:text"},
   2:{"text:text"},
   3:{"text:text"},
   4:{"text:text"},
   5:{"text:text"}
}
```

Here, keys are simple numbers ranging from 0-100000. Now i want to fetch by dynamic key data like, **fetch records with key ranging 2-4**, something like this:

```
{
   2:{"text:text"},
   3:{"text:text"},
   4:{"text:text"},
}
```

Any suggestions handling this kind of data with dynamic keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a given range, say 2-4, you can create an object with properties which are in **[`dot notation`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation)** to represent the embedded dynamic keys in the query. Constructing the object itself would use the **[`bracket notation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)**:

```
var i = start = 2,
    end = 4,        
    search = "text",
    query = {};

for (;i<=end;i++){ query[i+".text"] = search; }
db.collection.find(query);
```

Check the demo below.

```js
var i = start = 2,
    end = 4,     
 search = "text",
 query = {};

for (;i<=end;i++){ query[i+".text"] = search; }

pre.innerHTML = "query: " + JSON.stringify(query, null, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="pre"></pre>
```

Comment: i suppose this code is javascript but not mongodb query or map-reduce function? what am i suppose to do with this piece of code.

Comment: @Prasad.CH You can use the JavaScript in mongo shell since it is an interactive JavaScript interface to MongoDB